# How to make openmp running correctly in subroutine (c language)

Tags: c, openmp

I am trying to compare the difference between openmp reduction sum and the normal serial summation of an array. But I only got garbage number from my subroutine "fast_sum", while the result in serial_sum is correct. I am not sure why... I can compile my code successfully using gcc-7 -fopenmp. Please help me and thank you in advance!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 8

//////// serial /////////
double serial_sum(double *A, int N){
double sum=0.0;
int i;
for(i=1;i<=N;++i)
    sum += A[i];

return(sum);
}

double fast_sum(double *A, int N){
double sum=0.0;
int i;
#pragma omp parallell for reduction(+:sum) num_threads(NUM_THREADS)
for (i =1; i<=N; ++i)
    sum += A[i];

return(sum);
}  

int main(void)
{
int N = 256;
double sum1, sum2, sum3;
double *A;
int i, h;

A = (double*)malloc(N * sizeof(double));

for( i = 1; i<=N;++i){
    A[i] = i;
}

/* initialization A[N] */

sum1 = serial_sum(A,N);
printf("normal_sum is %f\n", sum1);
sum2 = fast_sum(A,N);
printf("fast_sum is %f\n", sum2);

free(A);
}
```

Comment: #pragma omp **parallell** …? Note that for such a small array, you'd probably be much better off with `#pragma omp simd reduction(+:sum)`

Comment: Thank you! But this does not solve my problem. The result I got is: `PRAM_sum is 1893031450094972697075119295257051103926535607546806559930980163878740732575927801924394608816190511850662975603137624841548607773607893700370643687326848998248607113581167693345707805185944792863675732747392195206578176.000000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an indexing error here. C is 0-indexed You never initialize A[0], and you try to access A[N], even though the array is only allocated out to N-1. So who knows what values are in A[0] and A[N] - they are probably quite large, giving you the garbage value.